# Alternative to picker view

Tags: ios, uipickerview

Is there any other UI object for selecting between variables that's not picker view?

I'm very new to iOS development, and I want to create an app where users fill out a form.

To choose between a small set of variables, e.g. "Male" or "Female", and "University", "High School", or "Child", I would prefer a drop down list, but the only thing close that I can find is a picker view. The problem is that a picker view is big, and it seems unnecessary when there are only 2 or 3 variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual way of handling this in iOS is to push a `UITableViewController` onto the `UINavigationController` stack, with one row per option. Use a delegate method to pass back the selected option.

If you want to show an already selected option, set the `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`

Answer (score 1):

I would use a UISegmentedControl

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Male", @"Female", nil];
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(35, 200, 250, 50);
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;

// replace self.view with whatever your view is.. alternatively you can also add a UISegmentedControl with Interface Builder in your XIB file.
[self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
```